# react rc-tooltip's tooltips won't hide after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip

I have a component with 3 buttons that trigger their respective tooltip when clicked, as below:

[image]

I use state to set the tooltip's ID so that at any time, only ONE tooltip can show. `const [visibleTooltip, setVisibleTooltip] = useState(null);`

The idea is, the tooltip's `visible` prop will check against state to return TRUE or FALSE to show that particular tooltip: `visible={visibleTooltip === tooltipId}`

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-react-react-rc-tooltip-why-other-tooltips-not-closing-after-state-change-lpcru?file=/src/btnTooltip.jsx:253-291)

What I expect is that when I click button 2, tooltip 2 should show up, closing any other tooltips. However, what happens is that all 3 tooltips show as you click through buttons 1-3.

I suspect the tooltip isn't being re-rendered, but I don't know why. Sticking a key prop onto Tooltip fixes it, but this shouldn't be the solution.

Using latest rc-tooltip 4.2.1 and couldn't find any answers here or in the issues of rc-tooltip's github.

Not sure if missing something really obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Frankly speaking, I saw the rc-tooltip codebase and it is not reactive to updates of tooltip component. That is why once mounted it cannot be visibility is just impossible to change. I found it prtety bad . Here is my try with the rc-tooltip. https://codesandbox.io/s/test-react-react-rc-tooltip-why-other-tooltips-not-closing-after-state-change-forked-xzf36?file=/src/btnTooltip.jsx But Later on I understood, it can never be solved.  i would suggest to move to some other tool tip  library

Comment: @simbathesailor thanks for looking into this. That's also the same solution my co-worker  came up with, it's very unfortunate. Maybe I will look into using another tooltip. It's very odd for a react package to not re-render on prop change...